# Where is Image are storage in Android Using Xamarin Form

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I am new in Xamarin,
I am using VS studio 2022, my APP take a picture in the emulator and then i need to copy the image, my problem is: Where does the image is storage in the EMULATOR? It will be different in production?
This is my C# code: string origenPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); to get the path where is the image, i do not know if it correct.

Thanks.

Comment: we have no idea how you are taking the picture.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot see your codes of taking photos, but in general, we recommend using [Xamarin.Essentials: Media Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?WT.mc_id=friends-0000-jamont&tabs=android) to achieve this.

The MediaPicker class has the following methods that all return a `FileResult` that can be used to get the files location or read it as a Stream.

- **PickPhotoAsync**: Opens the media browser to select a photo.
- **CapturePhotoAsync**: Opens the camera to take a photo.
- **PickVideoAsync**: Opens the media browser to select a video.
- **CaptureVideoAsync**: Opens the camera to take a video.

You can refer to the following code to  take photo and get the path of the photo:

```
async Task TakePhotoAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
        await LoadPhotoAsync(photo);
        Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync COMPLETED: {PhotoPath}");
    }
    catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
    {
        // Feature is not supported on the device
    }
    catch (PermissionException pEx)
    {
        // Permissions not granted
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync THREW: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

And you can also follow tutorial here: [Media Picker in Xamarin Forms - Xamarin Forms Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cCNnd8d-0w).

Besides, you can also use [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) to achieve this.